# QGIS not including Authorization header

Tags: qgis, authentication

QGIS 3.16.3-Hannover

I am trying to authenticate using oauth2 Authorization Code flow:

[image]

I think I get a token, because if I deliberately make an error in clientId or client secret I get an error.

But GQIS does not include the token when sending requests to GeoServer:

[image]

I was expecting a Bearer token in the Authorization header. If I try basic auth I do see it added in request headers, but nothing for oauth.

What am I doing wrong?